# Create a page turn effect in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm creating a online photo gallery app with Flutter where I want user to view the pictures with some effect like turning the page & the next image reveals. Every page should contain a landscape image which must be flipped from center horizontally. Please help me to achieve the animation. Below are the example what I want to implement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: soooo... does your animation work? Where is the issue?

Comment: I'm not able to create the animation yet... not getting any idea to flip the image from Centre of the screen...

Comment: what about the flutter app where you show what you want to achieve? where does that come from?

Comment: I already mentioned about the project in the description that it's an online photo gallery app.